# Getting a specific row value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

I have data for current year as well as next year in a table.

Sample Table data:

```
Year,Period,prd_Desc,Amount
2014,11,    Humira,  120
2015,11,    humira,  140
```

Key Coulmn are Year,Period,prd_Desc

If the data present for next year and for same period, i need that value in a separate column. Like below

```
Year,Period,prd_Desc,Amount_curnt_yr,Amount_next_yr
2014,11,    humira,  120,            140
```

I can achive this by doint a left outer join between same table using below query:

```
select a.Year,a.Period,a.prd_Desc,a.Amount as Amount_curnt_yr,b.Amount as Amount_next_yr 
from (select Year,Period,prd_Desc,Amount 
      from tableA) a 
left outer join (select Year,Period,prd_Desc,Amount from tableA) b on
b.year=a.year+1 and a.Period=b.period and a.prd_Desc=b.prd_Desc
```

I was trying to get it in a simngle query without using left outer join, but could not. If anybody can share any idea, that would helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your real table has some more rows (i.e. more years and more periods) than you show us, this would be a more generic solution:

```
WITH t AS   
    (SELECT YEAR,Period,prd_Desc,Amount, 
       LEAD(amount, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY prd_Desc, period ORDER BY YEAR) AS amount_next_year 
    FROM a_table)
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE amount_next_year IS NOT NULL;
```

In case values in column `YEAR` are not continuous, you can do it like this:

```
WITH t AS   
    (SELECT YEAR,Period,prd_Desc,Amount, 
        LAST_VALUE(amount) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY period, prd_Desc ORDER BY YEAR 
            RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS amount_next_year 
    FROM A_TABLE)
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE amount_next_year IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I said it jokingly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a subquery.

```
select t.*, (select amount from sampleTableData where year = t.year+1 and period = t.period and prd_desc = t.prd_desc) Amount_next_yr from sampleTableData t
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using **SUBQUERY**. Using the **WITH** clause, you can make it look subtle.

So, each year could be handles in each subquery -

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    (SELECT '2014' yr, 11 period, 'Humira' prd_desc, 120 amount FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT '2015', 11, 'humira', 140 amount FROM dual
  5    ),
  6    cur_yr AS
  7    (SELECT *
  8    FROM
  9      (SELECT t.*, Row_number() over( ORDER BY yr) rn FROM data t
 10      )
 11    WHERE rn = 1
 12    ),
 13    next_yr AS
 14    (SELECT *
 15    FROM
 16      (SELECT t.*, Row_number() over( ORDER BY yr) rn FROM data t
 17      )
 18    WHERE rn > 1
 19    )
 20  SELECT c.yr,
 21    c.period,
 22    c.prd_desc,
 23    c.amount Amount_curnt_yr,
 24    n.amount Amount_next_yr
 25  FROM cur_yr c,
 26    next_yr n
 27  WHERE c.period = n.period
 28  /

YR       PERIOD PRD_DE AMOUNT_CURNT_YR AMOUNT_NEXT_YR
---- ---------- ------ --------------- --------------
2014         11 Humira             120            140

SQL>
```

Comment: Thats a great answer Lalit. Thanks Dude